# Changing font-size HTML on different screen size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the website [markedsføring på pizzabakker](http://www.spotin.dk) and I just can't figure out how to change the `<h1>` to be smaller on smaller screens. Can anyone please help me with that?

My CSS for the `<h1>` right now is just this:

```
font-family:'Coustard', sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-weight:300;
```

What should I do?

Comment: This question is far more interesting than at first glance, but smaller screen could use a better definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matteo's code is correct. Try putting the code **after** the original h1 style.
If that doesn't help, try with:

```
@media screen and (max-width:360px){
    h1{
        color:white;
        font-size:25px !important;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions are right but you can also try with this one. Alter the current CSS code to have 5vw unit which means it will autmatically calculate 5/100th of viewport width.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries.

> The @media rule is used to define different style rules for different media types/devices.
>   In CSS2 this was called media types, while in CSS3 it is called media
>   queries.

Here is an example

```
@media screen and (max-width:360px){
    h1{
        color:white;
        font-size:25px;
    }  
}
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) for information.

To develop responsive website I also suggest you to see [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

> Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

Comment: I have tried to put this code example in the CSS file, but i dosent help?